# Vertical image are going horizontal on certain mobiles

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I have a website where users can post images in an article. The images are in portrait mode, and they always should be.
But on some mobile phones (Iphone X, Iphone 5C) (not my Redmi note 5) they're going horizontal.

Here's the **HTML** code for one image :

```
<a href="MyImg.jpg">
    <img class="alignnone size-large" src="myImg.jpg" alt="IMG_7768_1200" width="768" height="1024" />
</a>
```

And the **CSS:**

```
img.alignnone {
    display: block;
    max-width: 95%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.alignnone, img.alignnone {
    margin-right: 2.5em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    display: inline;
    border: 5px solid #555555;
}
```

I'm out of idea. Is this a CSS problem ?

Comment: This is due to the encoding of the image, not your CSS. They'll need to be saved again by the image owner, or you could provide the ability to rotate the image (via a CSS class) on your website.

Comment: Read more: https://www.howtogeek.com/254830/why-your-photos-dont-always-appear-correctly-rotated/

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with image's metadata. It was set when the camera took the picture. It's not something you can change with your CSS.

Comment: what does it means ? i can't fix the issue ?

Comment: You can't, It can't be handle from CSS or HTML

Comment: Thanks you. IS this possible in php or js ?

Comment: I couldn't found anything useful with java-script, 
I have no idea about PHP can solve this, but some server-side image processors are available in PHP.

Comment: The problem is that you'd have to programmatically inspect the metadata to see how the image is displayed to even detect whether there's a problem with a particular image. Better to let a human do it by checking a box on your website (which could add a CSS class with rotation rules), or direct them to save their images correctly.

Comment: You're right, thanks ! i switched from Rotate 90 CW to Horizontal (normal) with a meta data editor and it worked